# Cursor JOIN with same column name

Tags: android, android-cursor

how can I access columns with the same name? I have tried doing `cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("table.column"))` but it doesn't seem to work

Comment: when you do joins, use alias for column names and make sure it's in the projection.

Comment: I'm using rawQuery for this one. using alias also and tried Alias.column_name; still doesnt work

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use aliases, i.e.

```
db.rawQuery("SELECT column1 AS c1 FROM table");
```

Then you can use:

```
cursor.getColumnIndex("c1");
```

Obviously same applies for fields from JOINs.
Cheers.

**EDIT**

Example with join clause:

```
db.rawQuery("SELECT t1.columnX AS c1, t2.columnY as c2 FROM table1 t1 INNER JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.A = t2.B");
```

Then you can simply use the alias name regardless of the table it belongs to:

```
cursor.getColumnIndex("c2") should return 1.
```

Comment: I wanted to do something like `SELECT Course.image, Student.image FROM courses as Course join students as Student.....`  and then using `cursor.getColumnIndex("Course.index");` is this possible?

Comment: Use 'index', without the 'Course.' prefix and it works. You need a column alias for getColumnIndex() to use a different column name than the real table name.

Comment: Hi i have applied InnerJoin on 2 Tables 1 column that is primary key in First Table is foreign in the Second Table. Second table have 3 rows associated with the Foreign key i have managed to rawquery but don't know how to **Read** the cursor having 1 row from first table and 3 rows from the second table in one query.

Comment: @MuhammadBabar how is it different than the example above?

Comment: It's different like i have Table A having user_id (PK) and i have Table B having user_id(FK), subject. Table A having `one-to-many` relation with Table B. For example Table A has exactly one row while Table B has lets say 3 rows. So when i used join i get a cursor now i'm not sure how to read the data 1 row (table a) + 3 rows (table b) in one iteration!

Comment: `"SELECT * "
  + "FROM " + TABLE_STUDENT + " "
  + "INNER JOIN " + TABLE_SUBJECTS + " ON "
  +  TABLE_STUDENT + "." + COLUMN_REFERENCE_NUM + " = " + TABLE_SUBJECTS + "." + COLUMN_REFERENCE_NUM;`

Comment: Ok mate stop thinking i think i have found the solution there is a function `group_concat` that should do the trick. (P.S: It's cost me a whole day ;)